# Highlight the parent even when a child element is selected (opencart)

Tags: javascript, parent-child, drop-down-menu, opencart

Last week I created an e-shop with opencart. Now I'm trying to customize the default top menu. What I want to do is to keep the parent highlighted even when a child element is selected

I highlight the current page with this js :

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >
function extractPageName(hrefString)
{
    var arr = hrefString.split('/');
    return  (arr.length < 2) ? hrefString : arr[arr.length-2].toLowerCase() + arr[arr.length-1].toLowerCase();
}

function setActiveMenu(arr, crtPage)
{
    for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if(extractPageName(arr[i].href) == crtPage)
        {
            if (arr[i].parentNode.tagName != "DIV")
            {
                arr[i].className = "current";
                arr[i].parentNode.className = "current";
            }
        }
    }
}

function setPage()
{
    hrefString = document.location.href ? document.location.href :document.location ;

    if (document.getElementById("menu") !=null)
    setActiveMenu(document.getElementById("menu").getElementsByTagName("a"),extractPageName(hrefString));
}


window.onload=function()
{
    setPage();
}

</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

p.s. sorry for my English, if you can't understand what I want to make.

Comment: Tell us more about the problem.

Comment: ok. The code above highlight only the curent category. What I want to do is when I click on a sub item to highlight the parent too.

Comment: Yeah, you need to get the child parent and set class attribute to it. Use `.parentNode` attribute to access parent node.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you explain more? I'm a beginner in js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Tooraj gives me the idea. Here is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function extractPageName(hrefString)
{
    var arr = hrefString.split('/');
    return  (arr.length < 2) ? hrefString : arr[arr.length-2].toLowerCase() + arr[arr.length-1].toLowerCase();
}

function setActiveMenu(arr, crtPage)
{
    for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if(extractPageName(arr[i].href) == crtPage)
        {
            if (arr[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.tagName != "DIV",
            arr[i].parentNode.tagName != "DIV")
            {
                arr[i].className = "current";               

                arr[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className = "current";
                                arr[i].parentNode= "current";
            }
        }
    }
}

function setPage()
{
    hrefString = document.location.href ? document.location.href :document.location ;

    if (document.getElementById("menu") !=null)
    setActiveMenu(document.getElementById("menu").getElementsByTagName("a"),extractPageName(hrefString));

}





window.onload=function()
{
    setPage();
}

</script>
```